# correct way to install latest VS Code + .Net SDK + Omnisharp ext, and avoid error: "Attempted to update project that is not loaded"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I have a clean install of `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`.  I want to install `Visual Studio Code`, `.NET SDK 5.0`, and what seems to be the best suggested C# extension, [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), the `OmniSharp` one.

I first tried to install with the `Ubuntu Software` app. In `Visual Studio Code` I installed the suggested `OmniSharp` extension. When trying to build a project, I got the mentioned error.

I tried installing using the terminal with [this](https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/03/install-visual-studio-code-and-net-core-for-c-coding-on-linux/) tutorial which seems good and straighforward - same error, when at the console app example stage after running `dotnet new console`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535177/omnisharp-msbuild-projectmanager-attempted-to-update-project-that-is-not-loaded) SO question has three proper suggestions, though I would like to use the latest SDK, and I do not have Mono installed, also I want to use `Visual Studio Code`, as far as I know, that is a newer approach than Mono.

The `omnisharp.path": "latest` solution does not work.

Answer (score -1):

i faced the same problem  and in the end i find the solution here
https://medium.com/@stnlyli/visual-studio-code-failed-to-load-c-extension-on-ubuntu-5cc56dd1cdb7

prefix:
file->preferences->settings-> search for "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono" and make it never