# VSCode not showing errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I’m learning C# as my first language using VSCode (macOS) with Microsoft’s C# extension. It’s been going smoothly, until suddenly it **stopped showing errors as I write.**

When I write the wrong syntax, the "PROBLEMS" panel does not show errors. It only shows errors when I run the code. Earlier this wasn't the case. How do I fix this? [image: IMAGE HERE]

Through searching online I think the problem is with Omnisharp; I've tried re-installing the C# extension, re-installing vscode, doing the "Omnisharp: Restart Omnisharp" command, but to no avail. I saw one solution was to “start omnisharp,” but I couldn’t find out how to do that.

Extensions I have:

- C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) 1.25.0
- vscode-icons

**Solutions I’ve tried (none have worked):**

1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68013626/495455
[image]

2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72404936/224734
[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Add a screenshot to show us this, whats the problem no red squiggle underlines? What Extensions do you have - none that conflict?

Comment: Added! The problem isn’t ‘no red squiggles,’ it’s that the errors aren’t being detected in the problem panel as I write code. I attached an image for reference!

Comment: Maybe your code is perfect. :-)

Comment: @Skin its missing a semicolon line terminator. OP I'd be tempted to add the Unity tag to this question, its more and more looking like C# Mac AND Unity related. This solution keeps coming up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68013626/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson ah alright! I’ll try that solution in a bit and will update.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72404936/224734 ? There was an update of the c# extension and you may need to change a setting.

Comment: I seem to recall the last statement can omit the semi colon. Do any other mistakes show up?

Comment: @frankhermes I found the setting, but nothing changed. I added the image in the post for reference!

Comment: @JeremyThompson I looked for the closest settings to the ones described, though the error message shows up. (See post)

Comment: @BugFinder no errors are recognized; I tried using an old file where it worked before but nothing works.

Comment: i have the same problem, m1, latest macos, latest vscode, tried all the omnisharp settings change, latest dotnet installed , it does not output nothing on Run (even with omnisharp logging set to Trace).